# What should be the approach for reliable app using AlarmManager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm an author of an Android application that uses AlarmManager to send notifications to users. My app has to send notifications at exact time.

First obstacle appeared when Google introduced Doze mode. Fortunatelly, changing method to `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` was a solution for that. It was fine for a while. However, since 2 months, the number of DAU is declining heavily. And many users send me emails saying that notifications do not work on their phones.

After some investigation I know that there is Smart Manager in Samsung, Protected apps on Huawei and many other systems from different manufactirers that prevent normal behaviour of AlarmManager class.

So here is my question: how you managed to resolve that issue and let your users on any device enjoy your working app?

Answer (score 0):

With the release of Lollipop, Android introduced an API called `JobScheduler` to schedule task in a reliable way. 
You can use `JobScheduler` API to schedule your `Notifcation` to your users in a reliable way.

Check out the following links to understand more about `JobScheduler` API and use it in your app.

Docs: [Job Scheduler Android Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html)

Example usage of `JobScheduler`: [JobScheduler Google Sample Code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-JobScheduler)

Comment: [Doze restrictions... The system does not allow JobScheduler to run.](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)

Comment: According to @JaredRummler's link JobScheduler won't work in Doze mode.

But as I wrote in my first thread - I do not have any issue with pure Doze mode with AlarmManager. Using `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` does it's job. My issue is that vendors introduce their own battery optimisation mechanizms, that prevent correct work of applications which rely on exact notification via AlarmManager.

What is the known solution from developer point of view?

Comment: @Perry I'm not sure about a solid solution for it. But I think you should test it out on at least popular vendors

Comment: @AkshayChordiya, I've tested it on Samsung, Huawei, HTC, Honor, Asus etc. but still see that even though app works for me on devices from this manufacturers, users have a problem with lack of reminders :(

Comment: Hi guys, any recommendations in this topic? Or authors of great apps that rely on AlarmManager are supposed to watch their apps dying? Every week I see less and less user base in my app, after 2 years in the market, due to unreliable AlarmManager (because of Vendors' modifications and cleaning apps) :(